# Button icons are not showing on Run

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to display icons (all .png files) on my `QPushButton`s however for some strange reason, some are showing and some are not, which is why I cannot understand the problem.

Here is my .qrc file under my project:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>icons/auto.png</file>
        <file>icons/connect.png</file>
        <file>icons/disconnect.png</file>
        <file>icons/home.png</file>
        <file>icons/manual.png</file>
        <file>icons/measures.png</file>
        <file>icons/move_to.png</file>
        <file>icons/reset.png</file>
        <file>icons/spindle_off.png</file>
        <file>icons/spindle_on.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

which I created by using the Qt Creator's menu. So I have this under my `.pro` file as well:

```
RESOURCES  = myresource.qrc \
```

All the icon paths are confirmed and they load on the GUI design screen. However, when I run, I get only some of them showing, the rest are missing. They all have the same size, same extension, etc. I really cannot get what is going on.

[image]

P.S: I did run `qmake` after adding my resources.

**EDIT:** I noticed that my label (which has an image inside) also does not appear on runtime. So it is not only the buttons.

Comment: Yes, Strange problem! but there is a chance that different settings for button icons is causing the issue; So how did you configure the icons?

Comment: I only used the GUI. Set their sizes to all 90x90. What setting might have caused such a problem?

Comment: I know its strange, I would give a try to compare settings for a button icon that's working and one that's not (like "Normal off" , "Normal on" ..etc)  .. and set size to 60x60 .. some debugging is needed

Comment: Honestly the only different thing is their 2D positions on the form,  and those have to be different, obviously. I am baffled by this behavior of QT.

Comment: I suppose you set the icon images directly in QtDesigner ? Are the missing images always the same or is it random ? I suppose this is happening in main-window ? Do you run any code in the constructor before the `setupUi` ? And between that point and the moment you set again the icons to make it work, any particular code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply resetting all the button icons to default (no icons) and then reassigning the icons. I don't know what the problem was, but this solved my problem.